# django - cannot save password correctly in form

Tags: python, django, forms, view, passwords

I am trying to have a form that allows the user to change password.

Everytime I change the password, it cannot login. 
for example if password is "jake", I change to "jake1", I cant login with the password "jake1" or even "jake"

Here is how the form looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4fff.jpg

https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/employee/sign-in/')

def employee_account(request):

    employee_form = EmployeeFormEdit(instance = request.user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        employee_form = EmployeeFormEdit(request.POST, instance = request.user)

        if employee_form.is_valid():
            employee_form.save()

    return render(request, 'employee/account.html', {
        "employee_form":employee_form
        })
```

https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/forms.py

```
class EmployeeFormEdit(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("password",)
```

https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/templates/employee/account.html

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form employee_form %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-pink">Update</button>
  </form>
```

https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/models.py
Its just using the standard User model

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class EmployeeFormEdit(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("password",)   

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(EmployeeFormEdit, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

you must use `user.set_password()` to [set your password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords).

Comment: Thanks. I got this error when I add def save - "super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type"

Comment: I got it to work this way, thank you for the info:
        if employee_form.is_valid():
            employee = employee_form.save(commit=False)
            employee.set_password(employee_form.cleaned_data["password"])
            employee.save()

            return redirect(employee_home)

Comment: updated in git the fixes https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/views.py